# Using haproxy in front of Apache, reported SERVER_PORT wrong

Tags: php, reverse-proxy, haproxy, apache-2.4

I'm using haproxy 1.5-dev19 in front of Apache 2.4 (on Ubuntu 12.04).

Haproxy is listening on ports `80` and `443`, and Apache is listening on `8080` — yet, when I output `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` from PHP (5.5), it shows as `80`, when it should be `8080`.

That is, I would assume PHP sees the Apache server port, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What could I be overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `UseCanonicalPhysicalPort On` and `UseCanonicalName On` in the Apache configuration file will cause PHP to report the correct server port.

It's possible haproxy "spoofs" its forwarded requests so that PHP sees the requests as port 80 instead of 8080.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing these changes right now. Extra question: if I set UseCanonicalName = On, will PHP's $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] always be set to the ServerName that's configured?

Comment: Also, your answer states that these are php.ini settings — they're actually Apache config settings.

Comment: I made some edits to your answer based on my testing.

Comment: Whoops, nice catch. :)